# How to write if statements involving pointers/vectors?

Tags: c++, pointers, input, output

I am new in this website and C++. I am an undergraduate student and just starting to use c++. I have some knowledge on FORTRAN but c++ is kind of vague for me.

Now here is my problem,

I have a data file which has 9 rows and more 295242 columns. All the data items in the data files are numbers (decimal numbers not binary). The 7th row has only 0s and 1s. I want to store the rows in a separate file which follows the row containing 1 until there is another row having 1 in 7th column and put it in a do loop so that it could do the same thing with other rows also.

I tried using if statements with conditions stated with the help of pointers but I couldn't work out. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far and where exactly are you stuck with?

Comment: The description of the problem is too vague for me to follow. Can you clear it up? Or an example? Also this should be labelled as a C question too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a brief table of how pointers map to normal (i.e. non-pointer variables) and vice versa (assume you've declared the pointer as `int *varptr` and your regular variable as `int v`):

Dereferencing a pointer: *varptr v

Passing the variable by reference: varptr &v

Leave a comment if you have further questions and I'll do my best to provide more information.

Comment: Thanks friend. I just have one small question. I simplified my input file into one column. But I still need to find out the numbers in the input file whose difference is 17/18/19 and 20. The main problem I am facing is still again declaring the pointers to my input file data so that I can work out with it. I think I am having trouble understanding the working of pointers when manipulating the input file. Can you explain it please